# How to reopen electron application which in tray, from the dock or task-bar icon in Windows?

Tags: windows, electron, tray

I have an electron application which uses Vue for the templating part.
The application will move to the Tray if we click on the close button.
I need to re-Launch the application from the dock/app-icon/task-bar icon which is not happening.

Not able to re-open the application from Tray or we can say its already active.

Bellow is my electron main process code:

```
'use strict'

import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import { app, BrowserWindow, shell, ipcMain } from 'electron'
import { autoUpdater } from 'electron-updater'
import request from 'request'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
  global.__static = require('path').join(__dirname, '/static').replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
}

let mainWindow
const winURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
  ? `http://localhost:3600`
  : `file://${__dirname}/index.html`

function createWindow () {
  /**
   * Initial window options
   */
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    minWidth: 800,
    width: 1600,
    height: 900,
    center: true,
    frame: false,
    backgroundColor: '#1A1C1F'
  })

  mainWindow.maximize()
  mainWindow.loadURL(winURL)

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null
  })

  mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window', (e, url) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    shell.openExternal(url)
  })

  let cliArgs = process.argv
  ipcMain.on('get-cliArgs', (event, args) => {
    event.sender.send('cliArgs', cliArgs)
  })

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
  }
}

var shouldQuit = app.makeSingleInstance((commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
  // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.
  if (mainWindow) {
    if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore()
    mainWindow.focus()
  }
})

if (shouldQuit) {
  app.quit()
  process.exit()
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

app.on('ready', () => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Which command are you using for minimizing you window to tray ?

In our application we do the following for minimizing to tray and restoring the window when needed:

for minimizing:

```
win.minimize();
```

for creating Tray commands which restoring the window or quitting the app:

```js
  tray = new Tray('<path to app icon>');
  let contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
      label: 'showApp', click:  () => {
        win.maximize();
        win.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'quit', click:  () => {
        app.isQuiting = true;
        app.quit();
      }
    }
  ]);
  tray.setToolTip('app name');
  tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
  tray.on('right-click', () => {
    tray.popUpContextMenu();
  })
  tray.on('click', () => {
    win.maximize();
    win.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    // restore overlay icon when going back from tray
    setOverlayIcon(currentOverlayIcon);
  });
```

Comment: I used win.hide() command to move to tray. and in context menu win.show() command.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that the electron window is always running, even when the user is not using it? It seems to me that it would make more sense to close the window and open it later, when the user actually wants to look at it.